# Create a new column in a dataframe containing string values from different columns based on values in another column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

```
channel_paths['path'] = np.where(
    channel_paths['conversion'] == 0,
    ['Start'] + channel_paths['channel'] + ['Null'],
    ['Start'] + channel_paths['channel'] + ['Conversion'])
```

I would like to add string Null at the end if conversion is 0 and add conversion column value if conversion value is 1 .

*`I have a below error*

TypeError: Cannot broadcast np.ndarray with operand of type <class 'list'>

Comment: Remove the brackets around 'Start', 'Null', and 'Conversion' to use strings instead of lists

Comment: See below error    with those changes TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have dataframe like this:

```py
  channel  conversion
0     xxx           0
1     yyy           1
```

Then this will create new "path" column:

```py
df["path"] = np.where(
    df["conversion"] == 0,
    df["channel"] + "Null",
    df["channel"] + df["conversion"].astype(str),
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  channel  conversion     path
0     xxx           0  xxxNull
1     yyy           1     yyy1
```

---

EDIT: To append to a list in column "channel":

```py
df.apply(lambda x:  x['channel'].append('Null') if x['conversion'] == 0 else x['channel'].append(x['conversion']), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       channel  conversion
0  [xxx, Null]           0
1     [yyy, 1]           1
```

Comment: But my channel is a list of string which is causing issue